# How can I use a JS script or library inside a custom Web Component or HTML Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-component, shadow-dom, aos.js

I've just learned about creating reusable components and I'm trying to implement it to clean up my code. Before using the web components, I had jQuery and the AOS library working to get some basic animations on my webpage. However, once I create my custom web component, I'm not sure how to pass these scripts/libraries into my custom component.

I've created an example to show the problem. In this example, every animation that I've attempted in index.html is working perfectly.

index.html (below)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
    <style>
        .jQuery{
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-aos="fade-left">
        This AOS animation works. This text is inputted in index.html and successfully executes the AOS "fade-left" animation. (The AOS library scripts are included in index.html)
    </div>
    <br/>
    <aos-component></aos-component>
    <br/>
    <div class="jQuery">
        This jQuery animation works. This text is created in index.html and is animated using jQuery from test_jQuery.js.
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>AOS.init();</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="test_jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="test_AOS.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</html>
```

I created a "AOS-component" in 'test_AOS.js', with the idea of reusing this component. Every time I use this component, I want the same animation to load. However, I'm not sure how to pass the AOS library or jQuery scripts into this element.

test_AOS.js (below)

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
        .testingAOS {
            background-color: #dfdfdf;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="testingAOS" data-aos="fade-left">
        This AOS animation does NOT work. This text is inputted inside the custom HTML Element/Web Component (test_AOS.js) and does not execute the "fade-left" animation. test_AOS.js does NOT reference the AOS library.
        <br/>

    </div>
`;

class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

        //Do I have to insert a reference to the aos.js script here and initialize AOS? How can I do that?
      }
}

customElements.define('aos-component', CustomElement);
```

The jQuery script (test_jQuery.js) is working fine when called from index.html.

test_jQuery.js (below)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".jQuery").animate({
        left:'150px'
    });
});
```

If I create a custom element (such as test_AOS.js), how would I implement jQuery commands?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: https://robdodson.me/posts/dont-use-jquery-with-shadow-dom/

Comment: Dang, hoping there was a way to do it. Thank you anyways @connexo !